# How to make a script to test passwords on router settings

Tags: networking, router

I have changed the firmware of my router but now I cannot authenticate on my router settings. On 192.168.1.1 it requests login and password but mine isn't working. The login is probably root and I believe that the password has 8 chars.
So I want to try to get the password by brute force. I'm looking for suggestions to do it, like which language and something similar to look or if anyone already made that.
My experience is mostly C, C++ and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question.

The tool you're looking for is probably `hydra`. Note that brute-forcing will take a lot of time. You will be better of searching the web for default passwords and/or do a factory reset of the router.